# How do I solve Content not from webpack is served from in react webpack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am new to reactjs and I am trying to setup react, babel and webpack to convert jsx and es2015 code to 1 file.

The basic app is compiling well but I see the words below when compiling

> Content not from webpack is served from /app

```
[./src/app/index.js] 27 bytes {main} [built]
i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:1234/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /app/
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\coder\Documents\nodeprojects\my-react\src
```

This is how my webpack.config.js file config looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') + '/app/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist') + '/app',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/app/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

My project structure looks like this:

> project_folder
>
> > dist
> >
> > node_modules
> >
> > src
> >
> > > app
> > >
> > > > index.js
> >
> > index.html

Do you know how can I avoid **Content not from webpack is served from /app** or I don't need to bother it? Any help is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are new to react, I suggest you to use [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) to get started with the basic webpack, babel.

A project can be created with

```
npx create-react-app myapp
```

If you want to study their configuration, you can `eject` within your project:

```
npm run eject
```

Otherwise, your public path should not be exposed from the root path `/app`, but preferably `src/app` or better, just use `src`.

If you have a backend app and frontend app, you should make two different package.

Comment: I tried your suggestion to use `src` but didn't work. but thank you for this

Comment: Have you looked at the create-react-app configuration?

Comment: Not yet. But I think you are right to use the create-react-app config. Thank you. This can get me started to integrate UI